# How would I calculate EXPECTED income if I have PAST income data in mySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

Ok, I'm just curious what the formula would be for calculating an expected income over the next X weeks/months/etc, if the only data I have in mySQL DB is all past transactions (dates of transactions, amounts, etc)

I am thinking taking some averages and whatnot, but I can't think of a specific formula (there must be something along those lines) to take say average rise of income over time (weekly/monthly) and then apply it to a select future period and display it weekly/monthly/etc?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

use AVG() on the income in the past devide it to proper weekly/monthly amounts if neccessary.
see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg for more info on AVG()

Answer (score 0):

[Linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) + simple integration is probably sufficient for your needs.  I leave sorting out exact implementation for your DB up to you, but that follow that link to the "Estimation Methods" section, and probably use [Ordinary Least Squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares).

Alternatively, you can always slurp your data into something like [R](http://www.r-project.org/) where the details are already implemented.

EDIT:

For more detail: you're trying to model `INCOME = BASE + SCALING*T` where we are *assuming* that a linear model is "good" (it's probably not great, but it's probably good enough on a short time scale).  For [two value linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression), you're pretty much just taking averages; follow that link to "Fitting the Regression Line" and you'll see which things you need to average (`y = INCOME` and `x = T`).  There are some tricks you can play to simplify the calculation for the computer if you can enforce some other conditions (e.g., having equally spaced time periods + no missing data), but you'll need to math a bit more yourself first if you want to do that (and you'll be less flexible in the face of changing db assumptions).

Comment: Whoa... I kinda remember this back from Calculus days, but I have no idea how I would translate that into "simple" mySQL calculations...